# Substitute values of different column in dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, substitution

I have one dataframe `df_in` defined as:

```
import pandas as pd

dic_in = {'A': ['ff','rr' ,'nn' ,'qq','tt' ,'pp','uu'],
      'B1': ['33',r'\N','39' ,'22',r'\N','56','90'],
      'C1': ['44',r'\N','74' ,'34',r'\N','89','99'],
      'B2': ['33','63' ,r'\N','22','71' ,'56','90'],
      'C2': ['44','85' ,r'\N','34','52' ,'89','99']}
df_in = pd.DataFrame(dic_in,columns=['A','B1','C1','B2','C2'])
```

if I print it on the console it looks like this:

```
In [28]:df_in
Out[28]: 
    A  B1  C1  B2  C2
0  ff  33  44  33  44
1  rr  \N  \N  63  85
2  nn  39  74  \N  \N
3  qq  22  34  22  34
4  tt  \N  \N  71  52
5  pp  56  89  56  89
6  uu  90  99  90  99
```

What I would like to do is to investigate every single row of the columns `B1` and `C1`: if the generic row contains `\N` in both columns it needs to substitute its values with the content of `B2` and `C2` respectively. In such way the output (`df_out`) should look like this:

```
In [28]:df_in                In[30]:df_out
Out[28]:                     Out[30]:
    A  B1  C1  B2  C2            A   B   C
0  ff  33  44  33  44        0  ff  33  44
1  rr  \N  \N  63  85 -----> 1  rr  63  85
2  nn  39  74  \N  \N -----> 2  nn  39  74
3  qq  22  34  22  34        3  qq  22  34
4  tt  \N  \N  71  52 -----> 4  tt  71  52
5  pp  56  89  56  89        5  pp  56  89
6  uu  90  99  90  99        6  uu  90  99
```

I was able to achieve my goal using these lines of code:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df_in.iterrows():
    if row['B1']!=r'\N' and row['C1']!=r'\N':
        dic = {'A': [row['A']], 'B': [row['B1']], 'C': [row['C1']]}
        df_out = pd.concat([df_out,pd.DataFrame(dic)], ignore_index=True)
    else:
        dic = {'A': [row['A']], 'B': [row['B2']], 'C': [row['C2']]}
        df_out = pd.concat([df_out,pd.DataFrame(dic)], ignore_index=True)
```

Can you please suggest me a smart way to achieve such result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `\N` to `NaN` and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df_out = df_in.replace({'\\N': np.nan})
df_out['B']= df_out.B1.combine_first(df_out.B2)
df_out['C'] = df_out.C1.combine_first(df_out.C2)
df_out = df_out[['A','B','C']]
print (df_out)
    A   B   C
0  ff  33  44
1  rr  63  85
2  nn  39  74
3  qq  22  34
4  tt  71  52
5  pp  56  89
6  uu  90  99
```

If need add values by subset `B1` with `C1` to `B2` with `C2`:

```
df_out = df_in.replace({'\\N': np.nan})
df_out[['B', 'C']] = df_out[['B1', 'C1']].fillna(df_out[['B2', 'C2']]
                                         .rename(columns={'B2':'B1','C2':'C1'}))
df_out = df_out[['A','B','C']]
print (df_out)
    A   B   C
0  ff  33  44
1  rr  63  85
2  nn  39  74
3  qq  22  34
4  tt  71  52
5  pp  56  89
6  uu  90  99
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution where you explicitly state the case when you want to substitute the values:

```
import pandas as pd

dic_in = {'A': ['ff','rr' ,'nn' ,'qq','tt' ,'pp','uu'],
      'B1': ['33',r'\N','39' ,'22',r'\N','56','90'],
      'C1': ['44',r'\N','74' ,'34',r'\N','89','99'],
      'B2': ['33','63' ,r'\N','22','71' ,'56','90'],
      'C2': ['44','85' ,r'\N','34','52' ,'89','99']}

df_in = pd.DataFrame(dic_in,columns=['A','B1','C1','B2','C2'])

df_out = pd.DataFrame(df_in['A'])

def substitute(row):
   return row[0] if row[0]!='\N' else row[1]

df_out['B'] = df_in[['B1', 'B2']].apply(substitute, axis = 1)
df_out['C'] = df_in[['C1', 'C2']].apply(substitute, axis = 1)

df_out
Out[35]: 
    A   B   C
0  ff  33  44
1  rr  63  85
2  nn  39  74
3  qq  22  34
4  tt  71  52
5  pp  56  89
6  uu  90  99
```